# Remote Desktop Ubuntu Unity to LXDE

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, lxde, lan, remmina

I can do remote desktop on devices on the same LAN but both Ubuntus have unity as an environment.

I run `vino-preferences` and checking "Allow other users to view your desktop". Then I can use Remmina to connect to `[ComputerName].local` or I type in the local ip.

However there's a device having LXDE as an environment. I did the same thing with `vino-preferences` but when I try to connect to it I get a message "Unable to connect to VNC server"

The weird thing is that the reverse connection works fine. ...meaning I can connect to the Ubuntu Unity machines from the LXDE machine with remmina.

How do I configure LXDE to work like the other machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the issue was that `vino-server` doesn't run on startup in LXDE.

Running the line `/usr/lib/vino/vino-server` runs vino-server and fixes the issue the thing!

So we need LXDE to run this line on startup. I thought I need to create a desktop entry to run this line but there was one already. I fixed it by **commenting out *two* lines** *(and removing `--sm-disable` from the command. I'm not sure if it matters)*.

...so all you have to do is to edit the file `vino-server.desktop`!

Just run `gksu gedit '/etc/xdg/autostart/vino-server.desktop'` and make the file look like this *(you can just copy and paste)*:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Desktop Sharing
Comment=GNOME Desktop Sharing Server
Keywords=vnc;share;remote;
NoDisplay=true
Exec=/usr/lib/vino/vino-server
Icon=preferences-desktop-remote-desktop
#OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
Terminal=false
Type=Application
#AutostartCondition=GSettings org.gnome.Vino enabled
X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=Applications
X-GNOME-AutoRestart=true
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=vino
```

*(notice the lines `Exec=/usr/lib/vino/vino-server`, `#OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;` and `#AutostartCondition=GSettings org.gnome.Vino enabled`)*

Comment: You could also just add it to the Autostart tab in the "Default Applications for LX Session".